# Core data fetch records Group by relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

[image: screen shot added]I've two entities named `Expenses` and `ExpensesCategory` the `Expenses` has a relationship with `CategoryExpenses` with following attributes-
name-expenseCategory, Destination - ExpensesCategory, inverse - expense.
the `ExpensesCategory` has an attribute named expenseCategory of string type and `Expenses` has an attribute named amount.
Now i want to fetch expenses Grouped by expenseCategory with sum on amount.
here is my code

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortTitle =[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"addedTimestamp"
                                                               ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortTitle, nil];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Expense"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSPredicate *predicate;
    predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(addedTimestamp <= %@) AND (addedTimestamp >= %@)",currentDate, endDate];
        NSAttributeDescription* amtDescription = [entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"amount"];
        NSRelationshipDescription* nameDesc = [entity.relationshipsByName objectForKey:@"expenseCategory"];

        NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath: @"amount"];
        NSExpression *countExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction: @"sum:"
                                                                  arguments: [NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
        NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        [expressionDescription setName: @"Sum"];
        [expressionDescription setExpression: countExpression];
        [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType: NSDecimalAttributeType];

        [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:amtDescription, expressionDescription, nameDesc, nil]];
        [fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDesc]];
        [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

But when i run i got `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attribute/relationship description names passed to setPropertiesToFetch: must match name on fetch entity`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm still facing the same problem .. i really need your help guys.

Comment: If you post a screenshot from the Xcode model editor showing the object graph, that would be helpful. Click "editing style" at bottom of editor. Example: http://www.techotopia.com/images/d/dc/Xcode_4.2_core_data_relationship.jpg

Comment: @quellish screen shot added in the question, please have a look.

Comment: setPropertiesToFetch can only take property names (strings) or property descriptions that belong to Expenses. Shouldn't the "expense" relationship of ExpenseCategory be a to-many given what you are trying to do? I would assume a category can have many (expense) members, while an expense might have one (or more) categories.

Comment: Yes you are right a category can have many expenses and an expense can point to only one category, actually i'm working on an existing project and core data was designed by some one else.Better if you could post your answer including what is wrong in core data and code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer to your question.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ExpenseCategory" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *error;

fetchRequest.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(addedTimestamp <= %@) AND (addedTimestamp >= %@)",currentDate, endDate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortTitle =[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"addedTimestamp" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortTitle, nil];

NSExpressionDescription *ex = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ex setExpression:[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.expense.amount"]];
[ex setName:@"Sum"];
[ex setExpressionResultType:NSDecimalAttributeType];

[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"expenseCategory", ex, nil]];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"expenseCategory"]];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType ];

// Execute the fetch.
NSArray *matchingObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if ([matchingObjects lastObject]) {
    for (id expenseCategory in matchingObjects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", expenseCategory);
    }
}
```

If you are wanting to filter by Expense addedTime and not the ExpenseCategory addedTime, then change the predicate to:

```
fetchRequest.predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(expense.addedTimestamp <= %@) AND (expense.addedTimestamp >= %@)",currentDate, endDate];
```

Answer (score 2):

Whilst answering another question I discovered the cause of the specific error highlighted in this question ("Attribute/relationship description names passed to setPropertiesToFetch: must match name on fetch entity").  I am adding this answer to assist those seeking a solution for that error.

The reason for this error is that the fetchRequest's `propertiesToFetch` is being set BEFORE the fetchRequest's `entity`.  Changing the order of the code should resolve the problem:

```
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:amtDescription, expressionDescription, nameDesc, nil]];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameDesc]];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchRequest/propertiesToFetch) is clear that attributes and relationships included in the `propertiesToFetch` must match a property name:

> "The name of an attribute or relationship description must match the name of a description on the fetch request’s entity."

But it took me a long time to realise that this test is undertaken as soon as you set `propertiesToFetch` (rather than when the fetch is executed) hence the need for the `entity` to be set first.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `|expressionDescription|`, which is an `NSExpressionDescription`, to `setPropertiesToFetch:`; `setPropertiesToFetch:` accepts an array of ONLY `NSPropertyDescriptions`, and so is throwing an exception.

Both `NSExpressionDescriptions` and `NSPropertyDescriptions` ARE allowed in `setPropertiesToGroupBy:` however.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [pre-fetching](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdPerformance.html) technique. In this url you can find an example between `Employee` and `Department`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: hey mate thanks for the link, i didn't find any info regarding Group by in this article can you please add some line of code for me? Also i didn't get why it is giving me the exception?