# strftime SQL function in Core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to make a fetch in Core Data where I group by month of my property date.

In SQL

```
SELECT      SUM(total) as value,
            date as date,
            strftime('%m-%Y', date) as convertDate  
FROM        table
GROUP BY    convertDate
```

I don't see any function where I could use `strftime`.
Is there a way to do this with a `NSFetchRequest` instead of a `NSFetchedResultController`?

Comment: No, CoreData does not have a strftime or DATEPART equivalent.  And its groupby only works with persistent properties, not computed expressions.  If you want to achieve this with a fetchRequest, you will have to add a persistent attribute for the computed month/year and ensure it is kept in sync with the date.

Comment: This is what I feared. I know that Core Data is not an ORM but I'm a bit disappointed. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

you can do this by using `NSExpressionDescription`

for the grouped by With NSFetchRequest you can see [this tutorial](https://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/) or this [stackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957240/core-data-fetch-records-group-by-relationship)

For the sum here the `NSExpressionDescription` to add to your NSFetchRequest

```
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
expressionDescription.name = @"sumOfAmounts";
expressionDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.total"];
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;
```

For the date i think that you can format it by using `NSDateFormatter` when you get fetch records.

Let me know if this was helpful :)

**UPDATE**

```
[fetch setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:statusDesc, expressionDescription, nil]];
[fetch setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:statusDesc]];
[fetch setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
NSError* error = nil;
NSArray *results = [myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch
                                                         error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My only issue is to group by month inside the nsfetchrequest. I don't want to group after the request

Comment: i think in the tutorial it was the case. see my update

Comment: the fetch is the NSFetchRequest

Comment: I understand that i need to create a nsexpression but how can i get the month in the date. There is no function to get it inside the nsrequest